# Is there a way to get raw PCM from Deezer Android SDK?

Tags: android, deezer

In Android application, we're considering implement Deezer SDK with some post-processing of audio sources to boost up audio quality for end-users. To make it possible, we need to get raw PCM samples directly from the SDK but sadly there seems no such API. (I just looked through the API document. It has their native/android player providing play controls only?)

Is there a way to get this work? Or does Deezer has plan for providing such feature?

Thanks :)

Comment: If that was possible, it would be an easy way to download songs and persist them in any format on your disk. So my guess is, Deezer - as well as similar streaming providers - to the contrary will do anything to prevent developers from doing so.

Comment: I think that depends on how they restrict using their SDK legitimately by describing it in Terms of Use. Actually there is a famous service enabled this functionality. Many of audio developers want to fun stuff with it to enhance audio quality via DSP and FFT for visual spectrums and so on. I just want Deezer have a deep consideration to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, there's no way to get the raw PCM of Deezer's tracks using the SDK. 
As stated in the comment, Deezer needs to make sure that the music is not pirated in any way.

Giving away the raw PCM data would be an easy way to allow piracy.

About giving a feature allowing developers to apply post-processing on the PCM data, IMHO it would be tricky to make sure that the PCM is still not leaked, but it's a good idea for a new feature.